# How to run heroku pg:psql query in command line?

Tags: heroku, psql

After

```
heroku login
```

I'm trying to run in cmd:

```
echo "select * from public.table limit 2;" | heroku pg:psql -app "my-app::DATABASE_URL"
```

and get  error: "The local psql command could not be located"

The local postgres installed in : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
when I try to set path

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
```

or

```
setx PATH "PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin"
```

I get error like this:

```
C:\Program : The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How I can to run this ?

Comment: You need to add that directory to your `PATH`. Please see the marked duplicates.

Comment: but can't to set this directory to path

Comment: Please see the two new duplicates that are specific to PowerShell